# Error ZSH en parrot OS su

Tags: linux, bash, zsh

Mi duda surge que ayer empecé a hacer pruebas en Zsh (soy novato) y cuando entro en `su` se vuelve a abrir Bash, además si abro Zsh en `su` la configuración es distinta, si quiero modificar el .zshrc la conf está bien pero no se refleja en `su`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cuando haces `su`, te loggeas como superusuario, y ese *superusuario* es un usuario más.

Si instalaste `zsh` para que funcionara con tu usuario, no tiene porque funcionar con el superusuario.

Para que te jale deberías de asignarselo también a ese usuario como a cualquier otro.

En Linux puedes hacerlo de varias maneras y una es con el comando `chsh`:

```
$ sudo chsh -s /usr/bin/zsh root
```

**Nota:** No sé qué tan seguro sea cambiarle la configuración a lo que tienes en tu usuario root. Personalmente le dejaría a root todo casi tal cual como está y ejecutaría cualquier aplicación que requiera permisos elevados únicamente con `sudo`. No veo necesario el que root necesite de una shell más avanzada como zsh u otra.